# What is the recommended viewing order of Steins;Gate?

Tags: steins-gate

I looked up some info about Steins;Gate and there appears to be a new series out, which ended airing in September 2018, called Steins;Gate 0.

Considering there are a bunch of OVAs and alternative cuts, it's not super easy to figure out where the "full" experience is.

What is the recommended order to watch the *Steins;Gate* set of animated works?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-order-to-watch-the-Steins-Gate-series

Answer (score 4):

I think like *Monogatari* series, this is also a bit opinion-based question. However, going with release order is fine.

I would not recommend the chronological order for the first-timers. You will miss the references and 100% spoiled if you look at things like episode discussions.

By nature, *Steins;Gate 0* tries to explain a plot point you already know. You can watch the original *Steins;Gate* and call it a day, but by watching *S;G 0* you can get more of it **if you want.** It's like good old manga/anime discussions; you like the anime, then read the manga to get more of it.

Now, considering that, I think you should watch in this order:

1. *Steins;Gate*
2. *Steins;Gate: Kyoukaimenjou no Missing Link - Divide By Zero*
3. *Steins;Gate 0*

As for the movie and OVA, well, you can watch them after the original *Steins;Gate* or after *S;G 0*. But for me, watching it after the original *Steins;Gate* is better.

Answer (score 0):

The chronological order:

1. *Steins;Gate* episode 1-22
2. *Steins;Gate* episode 23β
3. *Steins;Gate 0*
4. *Steins;Gate* episode 23-25
5. *Steins;Gate* OVA
6. *Steins;Gate* movies

Comment: I actually tried this and it's not bad at all. But I would not try it the first time. Actually I want to try to add the gamma world line to this (there are small "animated" drama CD on youtube).